# Detecting AC power flow direction

Tags: power-supply, ac, inverter, energy, power-grid

I'm willing to design an AC power meter, which can measure power from a solar inverter to the utility grid and vice versa. I am using a grid-tied solar inverter to supply the load. This meter should measure power in both directions, whether the inverter is retrieving current from the utility grid or it is supplying the utility grid with current. So the question is what is the best way to detect current flow direction to determine power consumption from grid or power generation to the grid?

I've read on some websites that I could use a Hall-Sensor to detect the magnetic field of the current on the wires so that I could tell in which direction the current is flowing.  Are there any other recommended methods?